# Very simple CD ripper software free?

Tags: compact-disc, ripping, audiobook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What good, free audio CD ripping/extraction tools exist for Windows, and supporting multiple formats?](https://superuser.com/questions/2100/what-good-free-audio-cd-ripping-extraction-tools-exist-for-windows-and-supporti)

Hi

My mom got an mp3 for audiobooks, they come on discs. I need something that can rip the cd's and yet be really user friendly and free?

(She just started yelling when I tried to explain WMP).

Windows Vista. :) Thank you!

Comment: The ripper in WMP is about as simple as it gets.  Maybe buy her an 8-track next time.

Comment: omg...that's hilarious

Comment: What @typoknig says.  This isn't a software problem, it's a social engineering problem.

Comment: I've been using computers since I was 8, and I start yelling when I am supposed to use WMP...  Though, I can't say my tools are easier to use, they are more effective.

Comment: Have you (yes you) tried noise-cancelling head phones? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Audiograbber](http://www.audiograbber.org/).

> Audiograbber is a beautiful piece of
>   software that grabs digital audio from
>   cd's. Audiograbber can automatically
>   normalize the music, delete silence
>   from the start and/or end of tracks,
>   and encode them to a variety of
>   formats including MP3.

Answer (score 1):

[iTunes](http://www.apple.com/itunes/) can handle this kind of task and is very simple to use. An added bonus is that your ripped audiobooks will be nicely organized.

Answer (score 0):

EAC can be a bit interesting to set up, as you have to download LAME and direct EAC to its installation folder, but other than that it is really easy, and the best ripper on the market, free or otherwise.  Ripping is all it can do, but it does it well.